# Superconducting band equation as function of temperature using iterative method

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

The superconducting band equation is given by
$$\frac{N}{U}=\sum_k \frac{1}{E(k)}\tanh\left(\frac{\beta E(k)}{2}\right)$$
where
$$E(k)=\sqrt{\epsilon(k)^2+\Delta^2} \\
\epsilon(k)=-2t\cos k_x-2t\cos k_y-\mu$$

I'm trying to solve the equation by fixing the chemical potential $\mu$ for varying temperatures using the iterative method. I have multiplied both sides with $\Delta$ so that

$$\Delta=\sum_k \frac{U\Delta}{NE(k)}\tanh\left(\frac{\beta E(k)}{2}\right)$$
which is in the form $x=f(x,\ldots)$. Below is given the matlab code to solve this. I'm finding the following plot for $\mu =0$ ,$N=100$, $t=1$ and $U=0.5$.

[image]

Although, it looks good showing the critical temperature. There is a problem that it is too much sense to a number of lattice sites $N$. For an example, If I change $N=50$

[image]

it shows that $\Delta $ and $T_c$ are varying as proportional to $N$ which doesn't look a good thing. One would expect these to be independent of $N$. What is wrong here? It would be a great help, if you may point out the flaw.

---

```
function delta_new = gap(delta,T,mu,N)

delta_new = 0; % Initially set to zero.
U = 0.5;
% One dimensional Case---------------------
%     for k = -pi:2*pi/N:pi
%         epsilon = -2*cos(k)-mu;
%         E_k = sqrt(epsilon^2+delta^2);
%         delta_new = delta_new + (U*delta/(2*N*E_k))*(tanh(E_k/(2*T)));
%     end
% -------------------------------------------
% Two dimensional Case --------------------------
   for kx = -pi:2*pi/N:pi
       for ky = -pi:2*pi/N:pi
        epsilon = -2*cos(kx)-2*cos(ky)-mu;
        E_k = sqrt(epsilon^2+delta^2);
        delta_new = delta_new + (U*delta/(2*N*E_k))*(tanh(E_k/(2*T)));
       end
   end

% ---------------------------------------------

return
end


delta_guess = 0.2;
max_iterations = 100;
tolerence = 1e-6;
lattice_site = 50;
chem_pot = 0;
x = 1;
band_gap = [];
for Temp = 0:0.01:10
 for n = 1:max_iterations
   delta_new = gap(delta_guess,Temp,chem_pot,lattice_site);
   if abs(delta_new-delta_guess)<tolerence 
       break
   else 
       delta_guess = delta_new;
   end
 end
 band_gap(x,1) = Temp;
 band_gap(x,2) = delta_guess;
 band_gap(x,3) = number_density(band_gap(x,1),band_gap(x,2),chem_pot,lattice_site);
x  = x+1;
end

plot(band_gap(:,1),band_gap(:,2))
grid on
xlabel('Temperature');
ylabel('Band Gap');
```

Note - delta_new is the function that returns the right-hand side of the last equation.

---

I corrected the error pointed out by @MengCheng. But still, I find that the curve depends on lattice sites. I tried to find if it converges to a unique curve as $N\rightarrow \infty$ since my desktop doesn't allow me to go too far.  I'm going till $N=1000$.

[image]

From the figure, $T_c$ attains a definite value as $N$ increases.

Comment: It seems like in both 1D and 2D, you divide the sum by the same $1/N$, where $N$ appears to be the linear size of the system. However, it should really be $1/N^2$ in 2D.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you checked what happens if you increase $N$? Say, $N=10^4$?

Comment: @MengCheng Thanks! I added the edit.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker No! That's too much! My desktop can't take it. :)

Comment: It seems that the value of $T_c$ starts to converge for large size. This is normal, as the $T_c$ we usually discuss is the result in the thermodynamic limit, but finite-size systems can be different.